# ActiveMQ Artemis + JGroups + Getting OutOfMemory Error

Tags: activemq-artemis, jgroups

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11.0 (having JGroups version 3.6.13) and run Artemis in a master/slave configuration. There are two masters and each master has a slave. Please find attached screenshot of OutOfMemory error.

I have tried to reproduce this issue but not able to reproduce it.[image: m]

**Please find below jgroups configuration:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
<TCP loopback="true" recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:5M}"
    send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:5M}" max_bundle_size="64K"
    max_bundle_timeout="30" use_send_queues="true" sock_conn_timeout="300"

    timer_type="new3" timer.min_threads="4" timer.max_threads="10"
    timer.keep_alive_time="3000" timer.queue_max_size="500"

    thread_pool.enabled="true" thread_pool.min_threads="2"
    thread_pool.max_threads="8" thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
    thread_pool.queue_enabled="true" thread_pool.queue_max_size="10000"
    thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard" oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
    oob_thread_pool.min_threads="1" oob_thread_pool.max_threads="8"
    oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"
    oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
    oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
    oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="discard" />

<!-- a location that can be found by both server's running -->
<FILE_PING location="/opt/shared/fileping/artemis"
    remove_all_files_on_view_change="true" />
<MERGE3 min_interval="60000" max_interval="90000" />
<FD_SOCK />
<FD_ALL timeout="30000" interval="15000"
    timeout_check_interval="30000" />
<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="15000" />
<RSVP />
<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
    log_discard_msgs="false" max_rebroadcast_timeout="10000"
    log_not_found_msgs="false" />
<UNICAST2 log_not_found_msgs="false" />
<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="10000"
    desired_avg_gossip="50000" max_bytes="4M" />
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="10000"
    leave_timeout="10000" view_ack_collection_timeout="10000"
    view_bundling="true" />
<UFC max_credits="2M" min_threshold="0.4" />
<FRAG2 frag_size="60K" />
<pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />
```

**master-broker.xml**

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <thread-pool-max-size>200</thread-pool-max-size>
    <address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>
    <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

    <paging-directory>${data.dir}/paging</paging-directory>

    <bindings-directory>${data.dir}/bindings</bindings-directory>

    <journal-directory>${data.dir}/journal</journal-directory>

    <node-manager-lock-directory>${lock.dir}/artemis1-lock</node-manager-lock-directory>

    <large-messages-directory>${data.dir}/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

    <journal-min-files>50</journal-min-files>

    <journal-pool-files>100</journal-pool-files>

    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

    <page-max-concurrent-io>10</page-max-concurrent-io>

    <journal-compact-min-files>150</journal-compact-min-files>

    <journal-buffer-timeout>23480000</journal-buffer-timeout>
    <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

    <critical-analyzer-policy>LOG</critical-analyzer-policy>

    <transaction-timeout>1800000</transaction-timeout>
    <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>
    </connectors>

    <!-- Acceptors -->
    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.
        </acceptor>
    </acceptors>


    <ha-policy>
        <shared-store>
            <master>
                <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
            </master>
        </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>

    <broadcast-groups>
        <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <jgroups-file>jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

    <discovery-groups>
        <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
            <jgroups-file>idsk-jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
        </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>

    <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group" />
        </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>

    <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
    <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

    <security-settings>
        <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
        </security-setting>
    </security-settings>

    <address-settings>
        <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
            <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
            <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10
            </message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
        </address-setting>
        <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
            <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
            <redistribution-delay>10000</redistribution-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10
            </message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
        </address-setting>
    </address-settings>

    <addresses>
        <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
        </address>
        <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
        </address>
    </addresses>
</core>
```

**slave-broker.xml**

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <thread-pool-max-size>200</thread-pool-max-size>
    <address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>
    <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

    <paging-directory>${data.dir}/paging</paging-directory>

    <bindings-directory>${data.dir}/bindings</bindings-directory>

    <journal-directory>${data.dir}/journal</journal-directory>

    <node-manager-lock-directory>${lock.dir}/artemis1-lock</node-manager-lock-directory>

    <large-messages-directory>${data.dir}/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

    <journal-min-files>50</journal-min-files>

    <journal-pool-files>100</journal-pool-files>

    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

    <page-max-concurrent-io>10</page-max-concurrent-io>

    <journal-compact-min-files>150</journal-compact-min-files>

    <journal-buffer-timeout>23480000</journal-buffer-timeout>

    <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>
    <server-dump-interval>60000</server-dump-interval>
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>


    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

    <critical-analyzer-policy>LOG</critical-analyzer-policy>

    <transaction-timeout>1800000</transaction-timeout>
    <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61618</connector>
    </connectors>

    <!-- Acceptors -->
    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61618?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.
        </acceptor>
    </acceptors>


    <ha-policy>
        <shared-store>
            <slave>
                <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
                <restart-backup>true</restart-backup>
                <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
            </slave>
        </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>


    <broadcast-groups>
        <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <jgroups-file>idsk-jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

    <discovery-groups>
        <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
            <jgroups-file>jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>persistence-fs</jgroups-channel>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
        </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>

    <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group" />
        </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>

    <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
    <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

    <security-settings>
        <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="send" roles="amq" />
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq" />
        </security-setting>
    </security-settings>

    <address-settings>
        <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
            <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10
            </message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
        </address-setting>
        <!--default for catch all -->
        <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>60000</redelivery-delay>
            <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
            <redistribution-delay>10000</redistribution-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>50485760</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>10485760</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
        </address-setting>          
    </address-settings>
</core>
```

Comment: If you don't have a way to reproduce it at least share your full configuration.

Comment: I have updated my jgroup configuration in description

Comment: Please include the `broker.xml` files as well. Also, please elaborate on why you are using JGroups TCP with `FILE_PING` instead of the normal static clustering.

Comment: I have added broker.xml in description. If I used static its fix, no more dynamic node joining.

Comment: Are you in an environment where UDP multicast isn't an option, but you still want to allow a dynamic cluster configuration?

Comment: Yes, I still want to allow dynamic cluster configuration...

Comment: Can you tell me, how you did connect from your application to your cluster?

Comment: Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
 properties.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", "(tcp://localhost:61616)?ha=true");
 properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, factoryInitial);
 InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);
 ConnectionFactory connFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(connectionFactory); Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(userName, password);

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cluster have started first, it can be an issue of UDP multicast, my friend one question the only shared directory you use is ther artemis1-lock??

Comment: there are two lock directory (artemis1-lock and artemis2-lock) as there are two mater